# Array of an array of an arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to make an array of ann array of an arrayList in java for my sudoku solver, but I am having trouble creating it.

Here is what I am trying:

`ArrayList<Integer>[][] possibilities = new ArrayList<Integer>()[9][9];`

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What language are us using?  Regardless, just look up how multidimensional arrays work.

Comment: Without further information just a guess, but you still have to initialize each element of that array, i.e. `possibilities[i][k] = new ArrayList<>()` for each `i` and `k`.

Comment: You would be better off making a Cell class that holds the possibilities and answer, and then defining a 9 x 9 2D array of Cells.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 ArrayList<Integer>[][] possibilities = new ArrayList[9][9];
```

Of course now you have to still initialize each `ArrayList` inside the 2D-Array. But the above example should compile.

For initializing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possibilities.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < possibilities[i].length; j++){
        possibilities[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Then you can access each member like this:

```
 possibilities[0][0].add(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final int DIM = 9;
ArrayList<Integer>[][] possibilities = new ArrayList<Integer>[DIM][DIM];
for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++) 
     possibilities[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Initialize

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mylistoflist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And then you could add without problems like this:

```
mylistoflist .add(100);     
mylistoflist .add(200);
mylist.add(100);     
mylist.add(200);
```

If you add to mylistoflist you will add a completely new list, otherwise if you add on mylist you will just add a record to a list.
Hope it helps you

Comment: `mylistoflist .add(100);`Won't work, because it expects an ArrayList